# EF Core 7.0: Update parent version when child is updated one to many

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, ef-core-7.0

I am using temporal tables with EF Core 7.0, we have an entity with a one to many relationship. I want to update the version of the parent record when one of the children is modified. This will allow us to have a more accurate history when querying the parent records history.

I saw change tracking proxies : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/change-detection#change-tracking-proxies

And I know we could call Update on the parent to mark modified.

**Is there a correct way to map the relationship that EF Core will automatically do this?**

```
  /// <inheritdoc />
public override EntityTypeSpecificOptions GetOptions() => new() { IgnoreIdConvention = true };

/// <inheritdoc />
public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Parent> builder)
{
    builder.Property(x => x.Id)
        .HasColumnName("Identifier")
        .IsRequired();


    builder.HasMany(x => x.Children)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.Id);
}
```

CHILD

```
public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Child> builder)
{
    builder
        .HasOne(p => p.SomeRelationalField)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey("SomeRelationalFieldIdentifier")
        .IsRequired();
    
    builder.Property(x => x.Text)
        .IsRequired();

    builder.Property(x => x.BitIndicator)
        .IsRequired();
}
```

(versions and audit properties are mapped by convention)